# How to replace particular pattern/text from string in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server

I need code to replace particular pattern/text from string using T-SQL in SQL Server. The text or pattern which I need to remove I will get in a variable `@productno`. Product name contains `productno`, but it's position is not fixed.

These are some examples:

```
   Old prodname                      | prodno |              new prodname
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1) CORE TEST         G                   G                    CORE TEST
2) LCU 11-2   (SCOTT ET AL "A" NO. 1)    11-2         LCU (SCOTT ET AL "A" NO. 1)
3) Little Creek Unit (LCU) 23-11         23-11     Little Creek Unit (LCU)
4) SSFUZA 27-14      # 1                  1            SSFUZA 27-14
5) LAUREL FIELD UNIT 1-1 (1-7#4) 1        1         LAUREL FIELD UNIT 1-1 (1-7#4)
```

I will get prodno in separate variable ,Just I need to remove that from prodname and display newprod name, but keeping all combinations in mind

Comment: If I use simple replace ,say in example 5 ,i.e prodno is 1 ,if replace 1 ,it will replace all occurrences of 1 ,but I need to remove 1 which is at the end of string.Can I use any wild cards  in this case

Comment: How are you supposed to know which `1` to replace? What is the logic?

Comment: 1-1 , 1.7#4 are diff patterns ,when I say 1 prod no it should not associate with any other characters

Comment: can I use wild card charcters in replace function

Comment: No but it wouldn't help. What would you wildcard? `%1%` is still going to replace all occurrences of 1. Are you saying an empty space on both sides denotes which one to replace?

Comment: Yes,most of the time empty spaces ,some times #

Comment: Good luck. There is no logic that can do this kind of selective replacement on this kind of data with any certainty. You are likely going to be forced to do this manually.